# How to do grid update without closing window

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, kendo-window, kendo-editor

I have a grid with data. Currently I am using "Popup editing" and a custom template for this window.

```
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",
            window : {
                resizable: true,
                animation: false,
                modal: false
            },
            template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
        },
```

I want make the grid update when the user is looking at the editing window, 
but the window is closing when I do this:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

How do I update the grid without the window closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Kendo documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup) you should:

-set the grid's editable configuration option

-declare field definitions through the DataSource schema

-configure the DataSource for performing CRUD data operations defining its transport -> create/update/destroy attributes

And popup editor will update datasource automatically

Comment: Sorry for not very clear description. I don't have problems with saving. 
Data on the server can changing every minute. That is why  I want  make update grid on client side during that time when user looking on open modal window.

Comment: In that way i think you can define function on grid `edit` event and use `onbeforeunload` event of editor popup. In it somehow determine what is cause closing and cancel if need.